# Should we be using AspNetCoreHostingModel on Azure App Services for ASP.NET Core 2.2+ web applications?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking at publishing an **ASP.NET Core 2.2** Web API application to Azure App Services. I noticed that in ASP.NET Core 2.2 they have added in the `AspNetCoreHostingModel` setting.

[The documentation on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model) says that this setting allows `In-process hosting`.

> In-process hosting provides improved performance over out-of-process hosting because requests aren't proxied over the loopback adapter.

Question 1: By using Azure App Services on a Windows App Service Plan, does this mean we automatically are forced to use IIS?

Question 2: If that is the case (we are forced), we should probably set this value to `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` to take advantage of the performance benefits of InProc vs Out-of-proc ?

EDIT:

- My assumption for Linux App Service Plans is that IIS is not available on those, so this setting is ignored.

Comment: that's right My understanding is same , In case of linux it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

> By using Azure App Services on a Windows App Service Plan, does this
>   mean we automatically are forced to use IIS?

Yes, for windows app service plan, .net core app is hosted in IIS, and you could configure the `AspNetCoreHostingModel`. You could refer [Availability in Azure App Service](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/). And you could refer [How to check Azure App Service OS version, what version of IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/12/07/how-to-check-if-azure-app-service-is-on-2016-what-version-of-iis/) to see the iis version.

> If that is the case (we are forced), we should probably set this value
>   to InProcess to take
>   advantage of the performance benefits of InProc vs Out-of-proc ?

Yes, we should set `InProcess`.

> My assumption for Linux App Service Plans is that IIS is not available
>   on those, so this setting is ignored.

For Linux App Service plan, it hosts .net core app by docker. And `AspNetCoreHostingModel` will be ingored since it is only avaible in `ASP.NET Core Module`

Comment: Dead link to the blog is now here: https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/01/16/how-to-check-azure-app-service-os-version-what-version-of-iis/